# div gradually fading out on side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

It's pretty hard to explain, so let's take a look at this picture:

[image]

As you can see, there's a graduated rule on the center of the image. I'm trying to find the way to make it, using HTML / CSS.

My issue is:

1. **the background image** (here, the baseball game) **can change anytime**, so the ruler needs to be white on transparent background.
2. **the ruler is faded on each side**
3. **the ruler can be animated** (to see its markers scrolling)

My guess is it's not possible using HTML/CSS. I wonder if someone knows a way to achieve that using JS and Canvas (or whatever front-end technique)?

*EDIT: My bad, I forgot to mention that has to work with IE9 and above.*

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D I disagree. He's asking how to achieve a specific effect. Just because it could be done using CSS, Canvas OR SVG doesn't mean it's not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Yes, it could but it's still too broad since it could be done with any or all of those. If he had an issue with ONE of those then THAT would be a good fit for SO.

Comment: Well, what about the many questions about centering or filtering and ordering. My understanding of a broad question is: "How would I approach the creation of a RESTful API", not "How can I achieve this visual effect in a browser". Just because the answer CAN have several approaches, even ones using different tools doesn't mean it's too broad. In programming almost everything can be done in many ways.

Comment: Just wondering what are you going to be using the ruler for?

Comment: Personally I would do it as a canvas. That way you have full control over colour, transparency, spacing, tick size and more, with just a few lines of code.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you know how to achieve that with all the technologies I mentioned, I send you a medal tomorrow morning.

Comment: @johnny5 It a "timeline" animation effect : consider the baseball image as a slide on a carousel, switch the slide and the ruler should animate during the switch.

Comment: @enguerranws sick that should work perfect, as long as your not using that as a ruler

Comment: This is working nice right now, there's a bunch of CSS animations, but this one is tricky, so I asked it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easy to do things like this with javascript and canvas.

Just create the DOM element that contains what you want to overlay with the setting of the overlay as data attributes. eg `data-ticks-tick-width = "2"`

Then in the `window.onload` just call the function with the id of the element you want to overlay and any settings you may wish to overwrite. You get back an object that contains the setting (in case you just used defaults you now have access) and a method to redraw the canvas if you want to change any of the settings, or have hover effect, whatever. You can do as many elements as you want. You could also just search the DOM for elements with a data-ticks attribute and add the canvas that way.

Demo shows one way of doing it.

```js
var addTicks = function(container, settings){
    var name, defaults, step, ctx, canvas, location, x, y, w, h, tickCount;
    function getSetting(dataName){
        var val;
        if(container.attributes["data-" + name + "-" + dataName] !== undefined){
            val =  container.attributes["data-" + name + "-" + dataName].value;
        }else
        if(settings[defaults[dataName][1]] !== undefined){
            val =  settings[defaults[dataName][1]];
        }else{
            val = defaults[dataName][0];
        }
        return settings[defaults[dataName][1]] = val;
    }    
    function easeBell(x, pow) {
      // x = x*2;
      if( x > 1){
           x = 1-(x-1);
          var xx = Math.pow(x,pow);
          return(xx/(xx+Math.pow(1-x,pow)))
      }else{
          var xx = Math.pow(x,pow);
          return(xx/(xx+Math.pow(1-x,pow)))
      }
    }
    function createCanvas(){
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.zIndex = settings.zIndex;
        container.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    function resize(){;
        if(canvas === undefined){
            createCanvas();
        }
        location  = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        y = location.top;
        x = location.left;
        w = (location.right - location.left);
        h = (location.bottom - location.top);          
        canvas.width = Math.round(w * settings.width);
        canvas.height = Math.round(h * settings.height);
        canvas.style.left = (x+Math.round((w - canvas.width)/2)) + "px";
        canvas.style.top = (y+Math.round((h - canvas.height)/2)) + "px";
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = settings.color;
        ctx.lineCap = "butt";
        tickCount = Math.floor((canvas.width / settings.spacing) / 2);
        draw();
    }
    function draw(){
        var i, cx, cy, th, step;
        step = settings.spacing;
        i = 0;
        cx = canvas.width / 2;
        cy = canvas.height / 2;
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        ctx.lineWidth = settings.tickWidth;
        for(i = 0; i < tickCount; i ++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            if(i === 0){
                ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - settings.majorHeight / 2);
                ctx.lineTo(cx, cy + settings.majorHeight / 2);
            }else{
                if((i % settings.majorEvery) === 0){
                    th =  settings.majorHeight / 2;
                }else{
                    th =  settings.minorHeight / 2;
                }
                ctx.globalAlpha = easeBell(1- i / tickCount,settings.falloff);
                ctx.moveTo(cx + i * step, cy - th);
                ctx.lineTo(cx + i * step, cy + th);
                ctx.moveTo(cx - i * step, cy - th);
                ctx.lineTo(cx - i * step, cy + th);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
    name = "ticks";
    defaults = {
        width : [0.5,"width"],
        height : [0.2,"height"],
        'spacing' : [10,"spacing"],
        'major-height' : [20,"majorHeight"],
        'minor-height' : [10,"minorHeight"],
        'major-every' : [5,"majorEvery"],
        'color' : ["white","color"],
        'z-index' : [1000,"zIndex"],
        'tick-width' : [2,"tickWidth"],
        'falloff' : [2,"falloff"],
    };
    if(typeof container === "string"){
      container = document.querySelector("#" + container);
    }
    if(container === null || container === undefined){
      return undefined;
    }
    if(settings === undefined){settings = {};}
    "width,height,spacing,major-height,minor-height,major-every,color,z-index,tick-width,tick-width,falloff"
        .split(",")
        .forEach(getSetting);
  
    window.addEventListener("resize",resize);
    resize();
    return {
        canvas : canvas,
        redraw : resize,
        settings : settings,
    };
}

var ticksForImage1;
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    ticksForImage1 = addTicks("imgContainer");
});
```

```css
img {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer"  data-ticks-color="#EFE" data-ticks-tick-width="1" data-ticks-width='0.9')><img id= "myImage" src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/After_Plotting_Rice_Plant.jpg/1280px-After_Plotting_Rice_Plant.jpg' title='By Punya - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=35038411'></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Demo with animation. This is a quick hack and not the best way to solve animation. Just as a example of setting animation tweens and using requestAnimationFrame to render.

Added attributes

```
data-ticks-animate = 'true'  
data-ticks-start-in = '2000' 
data-ticks-run-for = '4000'  
data-ticks-end... animated attributes. see code for list
```

```js
var addTicks = function(container, settings){
var name, defaults, step, ctx, canvas, location, x, y, w, h, tickCount, settingsEnd,currentSettings ;
var settingsAtr = "width,height,spacing,major-height,minor-height,major-every,color,z-index,tick-width,animate,start-in,run-for".split(",");
var animSettingsAtrInt = "majorEvery".split(",");
var animSettingsAtr = "spacing,majorHeight,minorHeight,tickWidth".split(",");
function getSetting(dataName){
    var val;
    if(container.attributes["data-" + name + "-" + dataName] !== undefined){
        val =  container.attributes["data-" + name + "-" + dataName].value;
    }else
    if(settings[defaults[dataName][1]] !== undefined){
        val =  settings[defaults[dataName][1]];
    }else{
        val = defaults[dataName][0];
    }
    return settings[defaults[dataName][1]] = val;
}    
function easeInOut(x, pow) {
    var xx = Math.pow(Math.min(1, Math.max(0, x)), pow);
    return(xx / (xx + Math.pow(1 - x, pow)))
}
function createCanvas(){
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.zIndex = settings.zIndex;
    container.appendChild(canvas);
}
function resize(){

    if(canvas === undefined){
        createCanvas();
    }
    location  = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    y = location.top;
    x = location.left;
    w = (location.right - location.left);
    h = (location.bottom - location.top);          
    canvas.width = Math.round(w * settings.width);
    canvas.height = Math.round(h * settings.height);
    canvas.style.left = (x+Math.round((w - canvas.width)/2)) + "px";
    canvas.style.top = (y+Math.round((h - canvas.height)/2)) + "px";
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if(!settings.animate ){
        draw(settings);
    }else{
        startAnim();
    }
}
function draw(settings){
    var i, cx, cy, th, step;
    step = Math.max(1,settings.spacing);
    ctx.strokeStyle = settings.color;
    ctx.lineCap = "butt";
    tickCount = Math.floor((canvas.width / step) / 2);
    i = 0;
    cx = canvas.width / 2;
    cy = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    ctx.lineWidth = settings.tickWidth;
    for(i = 0; i < tickCount; i ++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        if(i === 0){
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - settings.majorHeight / 2);
            ctx.lineTo(cx, cy + settings.majorHeight / 2);
        }else{
            if((i % settings.majorEvery) === 0){
                th =  settings.majorHeight / 2;
            }else{
                th =  settings.minorHeight / 2;
            }
            ctx.globalAlpha = easeInOut(1- i / tickCount,2);
            ctx.moveTo(cx + i * step, cy - th);
            ctx.lineTo(cx + i * step, cy + th);
            ctx.moveTo(cx - i * step, cy - th);
            ctx.lineTo(cx - i * step, cy + th);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
var endTime;
var runTime;
function animate(time){
    if(endTime === undefined){
        endTime = time + Number(settings.runFor);
    }
    var progress = 1-Math.min(1,(endTime - time) / Number(settings.runFor));
    for(var i= 0; i < animSettingsAtrInt.length; i ++){
        var f = Number(settings[animSettingsAtrInt[i]]);
        var t = Number(settingsEnd[animSettingsAtrInt[i]]);
        currentSettings[animSettingsAtrInt[i]] = Math.floor((t-f) * progress + f);
    }
    for(var i= 0; i < animSettingsAtr.length; i ++){
        var f = Number(settings[animSettingsAtr[i]]);
        var t = Number(settingsEnd[animSettingsAtr[i]]);
        currentSettings[animSettingsAtr[i]] = (t-f) * progress + f;
    }


    draw(currentSettings);

    if(progress < 1){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }
}
function start(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
function startAnim(){
    endTime = undefined;
    setTimeout(start,Number(settings.startIn));
}
name = "ticks";
defaults = {
    width : [0.5,"width"],
    height : [0.2,"height"],
    'spacing' : [10,"spacing"],
    'major-height' : [20,"majorHeight"],
    'minor-height' : [10,"minorHeight"],
    'major-every' : [5,"majorEvery"],
    'color' : ["white","color"],
    'z-index' : [1000,"zIndex"],
    'tick-width' : [5,"tickWidth"],
    'animate' : [true,"animate"],
    'start-in' : [2000, "startIn"],
    'run-for' : [5000, "runFor"]
};
if(typeof container === "string"){
  container = document.querySelector("#" + container);
}
if(container === null || container === undefined){
  return undefined;
}
if(settings === undefined){settings = {};}
settingsAtr.forEach(getSetting);
var tempSettings = settings;
settings = {};
settingsAtr.forEach(getSetting);
currentSettings = settings;
settings = tempSettings;
if(settings.animate){
    name = "ticks-end";
    var settingT = settings;
    settings = {};
    settingsAtr.forEach(getSetting);
    settingsEnd = settings;
    settings = settingT;
    name = "ticks";

}

window.addEventListener("resize",resize);
resize();
return {
    canvas : canvas,
    redraw : resize,
    settings : settings,
};
}


var ticksForImage1;
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    ticksForImage1 = addTicks("imgContainer");
});
```

```css
img {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer"  
data-ticks-animate='true' 
data-ticks-start-in='2000' 
data-ticks-run-for='4000' 
data-ticks-spacing='50' 
data-ticks-end-spacing='20'  
data-ticks-major-height='10' 
data-ticks-end-major-height='30'  
data-ticks-minor-height='30' 
data-ticks-end-minor-height='10'  
data-ticks-tick-width='12'  
data-ticks-end-tick-width='1'  
data-ticks-color="#FFF"><img id= "myImage" src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/After_Plotting_Rice_Plant.jpg/1280px-After_Plotting_Rice_Plant.jpg'></div>
```

Comment: I actually thought about that, but this way, how can I make the ruler animate let's say from right to left ( and keeping the fade effect on both side) ?

Comment: @enguerranws Easy to do. Would just have to add some extra attributes for animation settings. I can add a simple animation to the demo.

Comment: @enguerranws Added animation. Sorry about the delay, lost the net down here.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will see if that fits my needs but this is surely a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do have a CSS option, however it's support is fairly flaky right now. I'm talking about the `mask` properties. As I'm writing this, they are unsupported in IE and Edge, and differently supported in Webkit and moz browsers, but basically for wbekit you have:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

And for moz you need to use SVG graphics in conjunction with CSS:

```
mask: url(#fade_right_svg_mask);
```

The examples are taken from [here](http://mir.aculo.us/2012/09/16/masking-html-elements-with-gradient-based-fadeouts/).

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a solution I didn't think about as I'm not familiar with `mask-image`as it's not really supported yet. Anyway, I'll use that, but I forgot to mention it has to work with IE9 and above (edited my question). Any ideas ?

Comment: While there isn't an easy canvas answer, many popular canvas libraries such as Create.js offer this functionality, and might be worth looking into. If it were me, doing this, I would actually create a short animation, several frames long, where the ruler slides to one side, while remaining transparent on both sides. This however would require some Photoshop (or similar program) know-how. After I have the spritesheet of frames, I would set them as the `background-image` of a `div`, and when needed loop the animation by manipulating the `background-position` property.

Comment: I will go further and look for some libs. I worked many times with RaphaelJS, but I will check Create.js aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Easy steps with canvas (loop):

- Clear background
- Draw ruler in correct offset position using either `fillRect()` using pattern+translate or lines + `stroke()`. Composite mode "`source-over`"
- Draw *mask* on top using either linear (or radial) gradient with transparent edges, or an image representing the mask. Composite mode "`destination-in`"
- Draw background image on top using composite mode "`destination-atop`"

### Example

[image: snap]

Tune lines and colors as needed (only alpha matter for the gradient though). This is just a rough skeleton - adopt as needed:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), x = 0;

// pseudo ruler for demo
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";  // needed if in a loop
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=30;i--;) {ctx.moveTo(i*10+0.5, 60);ctx.lineTo(i*10+0.5, 90)}
ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
ctx.stroke();

// mask
var gr = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,300,0);
gr.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
gr.addColorStop(0.5, "#000"); 
gr.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
ctx.fillStyle = gr;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);

// draw background image
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
ctx.fillStyle = "#07f";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Tip: If the linear gradient creates problem in IE9 replace it with a mask image. If OK I would recommend caching the gradient. Defining it doesn't cost much but rendering it does, so render it to an off-screen canvas and use that canvas as an image source for `drawImage()` instead for that step.